# ConTeXt: Span background graphics across verso and recto pages?

Tags: context, backgrounds

I want to place background images behind all of my part titles, with the image spanning across two pages, e.g.:

```
 ___________ ___________
|           |           |
| Part 1    |           |
| Birds of  |           |
| South     |           |
| America   |           |
|___________|___________|
```

So far, I have created this code:

```
\definelayer[patternleft][x=0mm, y=0mm, width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]
\definelayer[patternright][x=0mm, y=0mm, width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]

\setlayer[patternleft]                {%
    \framed[frame=off, align=right]{%
        \clip[nx=2, ny=1, x=1, y=1]{%
            \externalfigure[background.jpg][factor=500]}%
    }%
}%

\setlayer[patternright]                {%
    \framed[frame=off, align=left]{%
        \clip[nx=2, ny=1, x=2, y=1]{%
            \externalfigure[background.jpg][factor=500]}%
    }%
}%
```

I then put it in the document like this:

```
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=patternleft] % sets background for verso
\part{Birds of South America}

\page[right]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=patternright] % sets background for rector
\page[right]
\setupbackgrounds[page][background={}] % sets a blank background

    This is some text.
```

This has the following problems:

- The images are the same size as the twp pages, however, white space remains along the margins and fold.
- This sometimes places the backgrounds on the wrong pages.

How can I improve this code so that the background graphic spans across verso and recto pages on the `\part` titles?

Comment: Split the image into two part (see [\clip](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/clip)) and use the left part as the background for one page and the right part as the background for the other page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To expand on the approach @Aditya was hinting at in his comment, you
can chop whatever picture you choose as the background into fitting
pieces using the `\clip` macro.
First, set a partitioning grid using `\setupclipping`, e.g.:

```
\setupclipping[nx=2,ny=4]
```

This defines clipping to use two segments horizontally and four
segments vertically.
You can then address these parts using their coordinates:

```
\clip[x=2,y=3]{...}
```

This extracts the piece that is located at the third column of the
fourth row of whatever the macro is applied to.
Your doublesided background is a simpler problem as it requires only a
single horizontal split:

```
\setupclipping[nx=2,ny=1]
%% left half:
\clip[x=1,y=1]{\externalfigure[...][width=2\paperwidth]}
%% right half:
\clip[x=2,y=1]{\externalfigure[...][width=2\paperwidth]}
```

Now you just have to draw these parts as the background.
This is no problem in Context as all the [elements that constitute the
page layout](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layout) are derived from
`\framed`, inheriting its options.
Thus, in order to draw an image as a page background you can use the
same strategy as with `\framed`: wrap the content in an overlay and
assign it to the background.
The element that spans one entire page is called `paper`, and you can
configure it via `\setupbackgrounds`:

```
\defineoverlay [background:overlay] [\backgroundcmd]
\setupbackgrounds [paper] [background=overlay:background]
```

What’s left is to define `\backgroundcmd` so that it clips the left
or right half depending on whether the current page is recto or verso:

```
\def\backgroundcmd{
  \ifodd\pagenumber
    \clip[x=2,y=1]{\externalfigure[...]}
  \else
    \clip[x=1,y=1]{\externalfigure[...]}
  \fi%
}
```

Combining everything, a solution could look like this:

[image: doublesided page background]

```
\setupexternalfigures [location={default}] %% figure search path
\setuppagenumbering [alternative=doublesided]

\unprotect

%% 1) a named figure for inclusion, scaled to twice the width of one
%%    page
\useexternalfigure [half_cow] [cow.pdf] [
  width=2\paperwidth,
  height=\paperheight,
]

%% 2) a command that draws the left or right portion of a figure,
%%    depending on whether the page is recto or verso.
%%
%%    also, we install a counter to check if the background should be
%%    placed at all, since it is only desired with “\part” headings.
%%    this counter will be decremented with every invocation and reset
%%    whenever a new part begins.

\newcount\cowcount

\def\pickhalfcow_cmd{%
  \setupclipping [nx=2,ny=1,]%
  \ifnum\cowcount>0
    \ifodd\pagenumber                           %% clip right half
      \clip[x=2,y=1]
    \else                                       %% clip left half
      \clip[x=1,y=1]
    \fi{\externalfigure[half_cow]}%
    \global \advance \cowcount \minusone
  \fi%
}

%% 3a) define an overlay that we can use as page background
\defineoverlay [pickhalfcow] [\pickhalfcow_cmd]

%% 3b) hook the overlay into the “paper” element of the layout
\setupbackgrounds [paper] [background=pickhalfcow]

\setuphead [part] [
  page=left, %% assumption: parts always begin verso
  insidesection=\cowbackgrounds,
]

%% 4) define auxiliary macro that resets the background image counter
\def\cowbackgrounds{\global\cowcount=2}

\protect

%% Ready. Here’s some code that generates a couple pages.
\starttext
  \startcolor[red]

    \definedfont[name:IwonaMediumRegular at 22pt]
    \setupinterlinespace[25pt]

    \startpart[title=South America etc.]
      \dorecurse{5}{
        \input knuth \page
    }
    \stoppart

    \startpart[title=Birds And Such]
      \dorecurse{5}{
        \input knuth \page
    }
    \stoppart

  \stopcolor
\stoptext
```

*Update*:
Hooked the code into the part headings.

Comment: is there a way to wrap this in a function so you could import an image i.png from within a `\starttext \fun[img/i.png] \stoptext` and it clips/pans automatically across the next 2 pages?